# solr highlight entry mark all words

Tags: solr

I have a problem with solr highlight component. When I search the work `vim` bug I get result mark all words like this:

```
<mark>how</mark><mark>to</mark><mark>use</mark><mark>vim</mark>
```

I use solrj interaction with solr server. I just set highlight option like this: `fields = "title, content", snippet = 1, prefix = <mark>, postfix = </mark>`.

my schema is here:

```
    <schema name="onboard" version="1.1">
  <!-- attribute "name" is the name of this schema and is only used for display purposes.
       Applications should change this to reflect the nature of the search collection.
       version="1.1" is Solr's version number for the schema syntax and semantics.  It should
       not normally be changed by applications.
       1.0: multiValued attribute did not exist, all fields are multiValued by nature
       1.1: multiValued attribute introduced, false by default -->

  <types>
    <!-- field type definitions. The "name" attribute is
       just a label to be used by field definitions.  The "class"
       attribute and any other attributes determine the real
       behavior of the fieldType.
         Class names starting with "solr" refer to java classes in the
       org.apache.solr.analysis package.
    -->

    <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim.
       - StrField and TextField support an optional compressThreshold which
       limits compression (if enabled in the derived fields) to values which
       exceed a certain size (in characters).
    -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- The optional sortMissingLast and sortMissingFirst attributes are
         currently supported on types that are sorted internally as strings.
       - If sortMissingLast="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
         without the field to come after documents with the field,
         regardless of the requested sort order (asc or desc).
       - If sortMissingFirst="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
         without the field to come before documents with the field,
         regardless of the requested sort order.
       - If sortMissingLast="false" and sortMissingFirst="false" (the default),
         then default lucene sorting will be used which places docs without the
         field first in an ascending sort and last in a descending sort.
    -->


    <!-- numeric field types that store and index the text
         value verbatim (and hence don't support range queries, since the
         lexicographic ordering isn't equal to the numeric ordering) -->
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.TrieIntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>


         <!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime
         The trailing "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory.
         Optional fractional seconds are allowed: 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
         All other components are mandatory.

         Expressions can also be used to denote calculations that should be
         performed relative to "NOW" to determine the value, ie...

               NOW/HOUR
                  ... Round to the start of the current hour
               NOW-1DAY
                  ... Exactly 1 day prior to now
               NOW/DAY+6MONTHS+3DAYS
                  ... 6 months and 3 days in the future from the start of
                      the current day

         Consult the DateField javadocs for more information.
      -->
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


    <!-- The "RandomSortField" is not used to store or search any
         data.  You can declare fields of this type it in your schema
         to generate psuedo-random orderings of your docs for sorting
         purposes.  The ordering is generated based on the field name
         and the version of the index, As long as the index version
         remains unchanged, and the same field name is reused,
         the ordering of the docs will be consistent.
         If you want differend psuedo-random orderings of documents,
         for the same version of the index, use a dynamicField and
         change the name
     -->
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

    <!-- solr.TextField allows the specification of custom text analyzers
         specified as a tokenizer and a list of token filters. Different
         analyzers may be specified for indexing and querying.

         The optional positionIncrementGap puts space between multiple fields of
         this type on the same document, with the purpose of preventing false phrase
         matching across fields.

         For more info on customizing your analyzer chain, please see
         http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters
     -->

    <!-- One can also specify an existing Analyzer class that has a
         default constructor via the class attribute on the analyzer element
    <fieldType name="text_greek" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.el.GreekAnalyzer"/>
    </fieldType>
    -->

    <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- A text field that uses WordDelimiterFilter to enable splitting and matching of
        words on case-change, alpha numeric boundaries, and non-alphanumeric chars,
        so that a query of "wifi" or "wi fi" could match a document containing "Wi-Fi".
        Synonyms and stopwords are customized by external files, and stemming is enabled.
        Duplicate tokens at the same position (which may result from Stemmed Synonyms or
        WordDelim parts) are removed.
        -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
        <filter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <analyzer class="org.wltea.analyzer.lucene.IKAnalyzer"/>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- Less flexible matching, but less false matches.  Probably not ideal for product names,
         but may be good for SKUs.  Can insert dashes in the wrong place and still match. -->
    <fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- This is an example of using the KeywordTokenizer along
         With various TokenFilterFactories to produce a sortable field
         that does not include some properties of the source text
      -->
    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
             input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
             when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The PatternReplaceFilter gives you the flexibility to use
             Java Regular expression to replace any sequence of characters
             matching a pattern with an arbitrary replacement string,
             which may include back refrences to portions of the orriginal
             string matched by the pattern.

             See the Java Regular Expression documentation for more
             infomation on pattern and replacement string syntax.

             http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html
          -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="keyword" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
                          input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
                          when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- since fields of this type are by default not stored or indexed, any data added to
         them will be ignored outright
     -->
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" />

 </types>


 <fields>
   <!-- Valid attributes for fields:
     name: mandatory - the name for the field
     type: mandatory - the name of a previously defined type from the <types> section
     indexed: true if this field should be indexed (searchable or sortable)
     stored: true if this field should be retrievable
     compressed: [false] if this field should be stored using gzip compression
       (this will only apply if the field type is compressable; among
       the standard field types, only TextField and StrField are)
     multiValued: true if this field may contain multiple values per document
     omitNorms: (expert) set to true to omit the norms associated with
       this field (this disables length normalization and index-time
       boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text
       fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.
     termVectors: [false] set to true to store the term vector for a given field.
       When using MoreLikeThis, fields used for similarity should be stored for
       best performance.
   -->

   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="modelType" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="modelId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

   <field name="isPublic" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"  multiValued="false" />
   <field name="relatorUserIds" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
   <field name="relatorCourseIds" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />

   <field name="creatorId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="creatorName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="creatorAvatar" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

   <field name="createdTime" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="updatedTime" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

   <field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="attachTitle" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="auto_suggest" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

   <field name="level" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" default="1"/>
   <field name="score" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>
   <field name="viewCount" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>
   <field name="commentCount" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>
   <field name="voteCount" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>

   <!-- Dynamic field definitions.  If a field name is not found, dynamicFields
        will be used if the name matches any of the patterns.
        RESTRICTION: the glob-like pattern in the name attribute must have
        a "*" only at the start or the end.
        EXAMPLE:  name="*_i" will match any field ending in _i (like myid_i, z_i)
        Longer patterns will be matched first.  if equal size patterns
        both match, the first appearing in the schema will be used.  -->
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random*" type="random" />

   <!-- uncomment the following to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing
        field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error.
        alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want
        unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default -->
   <!--dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" /-->

 </fields>

 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>auto_suggest</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  -->

   <copyField source="title" dest="auto_suggest"/>
   <copyField source="content" dest="auto_suggest"/>

</schema>
```

what's wrong with it?

Comment: Please proide more information: Schema and query would be useful.

Comment: updated. hope it is useful, thank you.

Comment: Please clean up the schema. Removing the comments would help tremendously. Also, you wanted to post your full query.